# data modeling - alternatives to NULL foreign key?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, psql

I am currently working on a browser game. There is a map, each play has at least one village. Each spot on the map is either **empty** OR **used by a village**.

I have a map table with a list of all position in the map (empty and non empty spots).

**My map table:**

```
CREATE TABLE map (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    x_pos integer NOT NULL,
    y_pos integer NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (crop_type) REFERENCES. crop_types(id),
    UNIQUE (x_pos, y_pos)
);
```

**my villages table:**

```
CREATE TABLE villages (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    population INT4 NOT NULL,
    owner_id INT NOT NULL,
    position_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (owner_id) REFERENCES users(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (position_id) REFERENCES map(id)
);
```

So each village has a position BUT not every position has a village on it. Right now, I am not sure what would be the proper way to be able to find a location is empty or not:

- **empty**: all the `map.ids` - `villages.position_id` = every empty spots
- **non-empty**: `villages.position_id`

Example:

**map**

| id | x_pos | y_pos |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 34 | 55 |
| 2 | 10 | 15 |
| 3 | 08 | 89 |
| 4 | 65 | 12 |

**villages**

| id | name | population | position_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | london | 150 | 2 |
| 2 | paris | 320 | 3 |

Just to be more clear, every new user will have to choose a location to set up his village and of course, I will only give them the option to choose across empty spots.

This is one option that I may implement: add a new column to my map table, a **foreign_key** called `village_id` that represent the `id` column in the `villages` table. This will be an option FK so the value can be `NULL` because if a map location is free and does not have a village on it, the `village_id` will be `NULL`. My issues with this option:

- A lot of NULLS
- When a spot is going from the empty --> non-empty I have to update the `village_id` column in my `map` table.

**map**

```
CREATE TABLE map (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    x_pos integer NOT NULL,
    y_pos integer NOT NULL,
    village_id INT, /* new column */
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (crop_type) REFERENCES crop_types(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (village_id) REFERENCES villages(id),    /* new column details */       
    UNIQUE (x_pos, y_pos)
);
```

| id | x_pos | y_pos | village_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 34 | 55 | NULL (empty) |
| 2 | 10 | 15 | 1 (london) |
| 3 | 08 | 89 | 2 (paris) |
| 4 | 65 | 12 | NULL (empty) |

Is this an appropriate option?

In the game process, a lot of queries will be "what are the current available spots available to set up my new village"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, it doesn't really matter. If the foreign key is on `villages` (and pointing to `map`), it will be efficient enough to find all the spots on the `map` without a village, as long as there is an index on `villages.position_id`:

```
select
    m.*
from
    map as m
where
    not exists(select from villages as v where v.position_id = m.id)
;
```

Since each spot on the map can be used only once, you can make `villages.position_id` `UNIQUE`, which will take care of the index you need for decent performance:

```sql
CREATE TABLE villages (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    population INT4 NOT NULL,
    owner_id INT NOT NULL,
    position_id INT NOT NULL UNIQUE,  -- Added UNIQUE
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (owner_id) REFERENCES users(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (position_id) REFERENCES map(id)
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion BigSmoke, seems right